# Create database tables from models in django 1.10 with Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have multiple models that I'd like to create tables for. So far I've been running sql code to create them and then i can make use of them. This seems tedious and I'm pretty sure django can do it for me. After all it creates tables with makemigrations and migrate. But this does not seem to work with my models.

EDIT: Here's what I mean

I have a model like the following

```
class Article(models.Model):
        headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        content = models.TextField()
        ...

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'main_article'
```

So far I've been creating the main_article table manually by running this code in psycopg2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.main_article (
id                      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
headline                varchar 200 NOT NULL,
content                 text NOT NULL,
...
);
```

This is a real pain and I'm sure it will lead to errors and bugs. How can i get this table to be created automatically? I tried doing

> python manage.py makemigrations main
>
> python manage.py migrate main

With no success.
Btw 'main' is the name of my app.
Hope it's more clear now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as the commands you run and the error messages they generate?

Comment: For additional info, please add your model and `INSTALLED_APPS` configuration.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. makemigrations and migrate do **not** create databases; in fact creating tables is exactly what they do. So you need to explain in a bit more detail what you are doing with those commands and with the raw SQL, and what issues you are doing.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04 follow the tutorial.

Comment: Just too clarify, I'm not getting any errors. I'm just looking for the proper way of doing this in the hopes of getting fewer bugs later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still wondering, my problem was that I had set managed to false. Simply changing this did the trick.